# `&&` and `||` replacing `if`-`else`-statement?

Tags: ruby

Can somebody please explain how to interpret the following excerpt of a ruby block?

```
s = "one"
s.length > 1 && s.reverse! || s
```

returns

```
"eno"
```

How is it possible that the expression substitutes an `if`-`else`-statement?

Comment: That doesn't return `ONE`, it returns `eno`. And the operator precedence for those is left to right.

Comment: Jep, copied from the wrong workspace, edited the original post

Comment: you want result as "ONE" when length of s is greater than 1?

Comment: See my comment above

Answer (score 2):

The expression on the right side of the `&&` operator only gets evaluated if the expression on the left evaluates to a truthy value (anything but `nil` or `false`).  This is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).  The basic idea is that if the left side evaluates to false, we know the overall value of the `&&` operator will be false, so let's save some CPU time (and avoid some side effects) by not even evaluating the the expression on the right.

So the line

```
s.length > 1 && s.reverse!
```

is equivalent to

```
if s.length > 1
  s.reverse!
end
```

Answer (score 1):

When `s.length > 1` is truthy, `s.reverse!` is evaluated to see if it is further truthy. If it is, then `s.length > 1 && s.reverse!` is evaluated to be truthy. In such case, `s` is not evaluated. Otherwise, `s` is evaluated.

So it is not the same as

```
if s.length > 1
  s.reverse!
else
  s
end
```

but is the same as

```
if s.length > 1 and s.reverse!
else
  s
end
```

Comment: Mmhhhh, but how can a method not returning bool become evaluated as you suggest?

Comment: In Ruby, any object can take place in logical operations.

Comment: Ok, I checked it on the console, makes sense. But then, what's the final interpretation: pure boolean logic or - like David Grayson - stated short-circuit evaluation? As I understood the latter would mean, that the `reverse!`-method does not get touched if `s.length > n` evaluates to `false`

Comment: As I wrote, it returns a truthy value (anything but `false` or `nil`) or a falsy value (`false` or `nil`), whatever is returned from the components.

Comment: Yes, I got that. Please check the first answer to the question. I interpret it to be different from yours and now want to know if a) this is true and if so b) what is the right answer... Anyhow, thanks for your time ;-)

Comment: The first answer is discussing a part of your expression, and it is correct. My answer is  about the whole expression.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. So I'd translate everything that's been said to the following: `s.reverse`will always be evaluated as true. Since the whole expression is evaluated in short-circuit manner the outcome of the `length`-check determines whether the `!` in `s.reverse!` applies the reversing to the string. If the `length`-check fails the expression simply returns the string.